# Can you store an operation as a variable?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a calculator and I would like to allow the user to input what operation they want to use. But I need to be able to store that as a variable so it can be used later. The problem is that I don't know what variable type I would store it as and how I would use it between two other variables so the program treats it as a mathematical operation.

The variables I have are `x`, `y`, and `op`, so would I do something like x(op)y or x op y? Or are both of those wrong?

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Yep you can. It’s called a delegate

Comment: You can, in fact, store an operation as a variable -- `Func<int, int, int> add = (x, y) => x + y`. Of course the user wouldn't enter that, but you could have a `Dictionary<char, Func<int, int, int>>` mapping input like `'+'` to an appropriate operation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your exact requirements are, but I would suggest creating a class:

```
public class Operation  {

    // Stores the RHS value
    public decimal Right { get; set; }

    // Stores the LHS value
    public decimal Left { get; set; }

    // Stores the operator '+', '-', '*', '/'
    // for ease-of-printing
    public char Operation { get; set; }

    // Stores the actual code object that will give the result
    public Func<decimal, decimal, decimal> Function { get; set; }
}
```

With this setup, you can including parsing logic and print logic while allowing your program to work with the data itself more easily. Of course, you could also create a grammar, combine that with a lexer and parser to get the output and then all you'd need to store would be the string variable itself (see [here](https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-csharp/)). Even with that approach, however, you'd want to store this information to avoid processing it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `delegates`. Delegates are basically references to a function. Here is how they look like:

```
Func<int, int, int> sum = (x, y) => x + y;
```

You can have one delegate for every operation you need.

Answer (score 0):

continuing others comments, you can even put them in a Dictionary, so that you can look them up and execute based on what the user enters

```
        var ops = new Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, int>>(){
            {"+", (x,y) => x+y},
            {"-", (x,y) => x-y},
            {"*", (x,y) => x*y}
        };

        // user input
        var opStr = "+";
        var x = 4;
        var y = 2;

        // compute result  
        var res = ops[opStr](x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are certainly a quick way to solve this problem. But if you want to work towards a more complex calculator, I'd suggest building an "Abstract Syntax Tree". A graph of objects that define a maths equation, with each node representing either a value or an operator. For example;

```cs
public abstract class Ast
{
    public abstract double Calculate();
}
public class AstValue : Ast
{
    public readonly double Value;
    public AstValue(double value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public override double Calculate() => Value;
    public override string ToString() => Value.ToString();
}
public class AstAdd : Ast
{
    public readonly Ast Left;
    public readonly Ast Right;
    public AstAdd(Ast left, Ast right)
    {
        Left = left;
        Right = right;
    }
    public override double Calculate() => Left.Calculate() + Right.Calculate();
    public override string ToString() => $"{Left} + {Right}";
}

var formula = new AstAdd(new AstAdd(new AstValue(1), new AstValue(2)), new AstValue(3));
var result = formula.Calculate();
```